# Error building iText Examples (Sandbox) 5.5.11-SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven, itext

I am trying to build the project

https://github.com/itext/i5js-sandbox/

I've tried

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
mvn update
mvn package
```

but I got this error

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.11-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:jar:5.5.11-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.itextpdf:itext-pdfa:jar:5.5.11-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.itextpdf:itext-xtra:jar:5.5.11-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to build the examples without first building the jars on which the examples depend. You have two options:

- Either use iText 5.5.10 instead of 5.5.11-SNAPSHOT. 5.5.10 has been officially released and the jars you need are published on the Maven Central repository.
- Or use iText 5.5.11-SNAPSHOT and build *everything* yourself. Mind the word *everything*, starting with the core.

Suppose that you were building a house. You are trying to build the roof in the air, and you complain that the roof falls down. That's wrong. You shouldn't start with the roof. You should start with the foundations and the walls.

Comment: Based on this question, I added some information to README.md: https://github.com/itext/i5js-sandbox/blob/master/README.md. Pull requests are always welcome, especially for documentation!